# Чистая архитектура, как отделить работу с сетью (Куда вынести логику проверки токена)?

Tags: android, архитектура, retrofit2, rxjava2

У юзера есть Token который в любой момент времени может стать не валидным.
Понятно что токен проверять в doOnEvent не вариант (дубликация кода в каждом запросе) и не понимаю **как и куда вынести логику проверки токена?**
Может кто дать ссылку на примеры?

Использую MVVM, Retrofit2, RxJava2

код:

```
//NetworkApi
@POST("user/start")
fun loadCatalog(@Field catalogId: Int) : Single<Response<List<Catalog>>>

//ViewModel
val catalog: MutableLiveData<List<Catalog>> = MutableLiveData()

fun loadCatalogById(catalogId: Int) {
  dataManager.loadCatalog(catalogId)
          .doOnEvent { response, throwable ->
            runOnUiThread {
              if(response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                  //TODO перейти на экран авторизации
              }
              else
                response?.errorBody()?.string()?.let { dataLoadFailure.value = it }
            }
          }
          .filter { it.isSuccessful }
          .map { it.body()!! }
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe({ catalog.value = it }) { dataLoadError.value = it }
}
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что у вас не получается. Вот в TODO вызовите метод getToken(),  а потом снова вызовите метод loadCatalogById

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо сделать примерно так:

1. При создании экземпляра Retrofit передать в его билдер реализацию интерфейса `Interceptor`.
2. В этой реализации вы можете проверить каков ответ сервера и, если он `401`, то сделать запрос на получение токена и повторить запрос.

Таким образом у вас это будет происходить автоматически для всех запросов.

Comment: Спасибо за совет но это не совсем то что мне нужно. В моём случае может прийти не только 401, Допустим сервер также может прислать и ответ 500+ (ошибка на стороне сервера) и на неё нужно как то реагировать. Писать в каждом запросе проверку на HTTP коды, как я уже сказал не правильно, но как правильно я не знаю. Мне нужно вынести логику обработки ошибок как то/куда то. или я чего то не понимаю...

Comment: Если сервер написан правильно, то при протухшем токене придти может только 401. Если вам надо отдельно обрабатывать 500+ ошибки - создайте для этого класс с методом, принимающим ошибку. В нём её обработайте. Во все ваши классы с rx цепочками прокиньте экземпляр класса и вызывайте его метод в onError. Можно ещё и базовых классов наделать, которые будут onErrorResumeNext добавлять во все цепочки или ещё очень много способов. Какой именно код писать - во многом зависит от того, что вам нужно и как вам удобнее и что красивее кажется.